# Formatação de Arquivo em Python

Tags: python-3.x, arquivo

Olá, sou iniciante em Python e estou trabalhando com processamento de linguagem natural. Ao processar um texto e separar as sentenças, Quero gravar dessa maneira no arquivo << SENTENÇA >> << SENTENÇA >> ... Mas não sei como fazer isso, sei como printar na tela, mas não como gravar no arquivo nesse formato.
Se alguém puder me dar um hel agradeço muito

```
import nltk
import nltk.data


arquivo = open('base_setenciado.txt', 'w')

raw_text = open('base.txt').read()

sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/portuguese.pickle')

sentences = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(raw_text)

for sent in sentences[500:505]:

    print("<<", sent, ">>\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você já está acostumada a usar [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) pode passar o seu arquivo como argumento `file` para `print()` que ele fará o print no arquivo, ao invés do `sys.stdout` como de costume.

Ex.:

```
import nltk
import nltk.data

raw_text = open('base.txt').read()
sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/portuguese.pickle')
sentences = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(raw_text)

with open('base_setenciado.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    for sent in sentences[500:505]:
        print("<<", sent, ">>\n", file=arquivo)
```